# How do Check/Uncheck a checkbox input with value property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multy checkbox with value.

```js
$(".content-items input[name=Category[]']").prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<ul class="me-list">
  <li>
    <label class="container">
            Filter1
       <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="1" name="category[]" />
       <span class="checkmark"/>
      </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="container">
            Filter2
       <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]" />
       <span class="checkmark"/>
      </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="container">
            Filter1
       <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="5" name="category[] />
       <span class="checkmark"/>
      </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to uncheck checkbox when `name=Category[]` and `Value=5`

when i use this code , it is uncheck all checkbox with same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`attributeMultiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

You also have typos in the name attribute value (`Category[]` should be `category[]`).

**Please Note:** If *tagName* and *class* specify the same element, you should use *tagName.className*. You also have to wrap the attribute value with quote if it consist `[]`.

```js
$("input.content-items[name='category[]'][value=5]").prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="me-list">
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" checked value="1" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter2
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" checked value="3" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" checked value="5" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using the selectors a bit wrong, you would want `input` with `content-items` as class, name as `category[]` and value equal to `5`. Use single quotes with double quotes inside the selector or vice-versa to get the exact match of the attribute value. The following should do it:

```js
//uncheck all
$('input.content-items[name="category[]"]').prop('checked', false);
//check desired
$('input.content-items[name="category[]"][value="5"]').prop('checked', "checked" /*true*/);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="me-list">
  <li>
    <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="1" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="container">
    Filter2
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="5" name="category[]">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your query selector is wrong. To select `input` (or any other element) you write it first in the query.

Classes are selected by prepending a dot `.` before them. So, to select an element with a specific class, you would write `input.content-items`.

To select an element with specific attribute, you write `[name='category[]']`. You must surround the value you are selecting with quotation marks. To select by multiple attributes, you just write them one after another.

So your selector would be -

```js
$("input.content-items[name='category[]'][value=5]");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/de8w4f7t/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change your selector to `$("input[name='category[]'][value=5]")`

Demo:

```js
$('#uncheck').on("click", function() {
  $("input[name='category[]'][value=5]").prop('checked', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="me-list">
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="1" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter2
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="5" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <button id="uncheck">uncheck</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your query selector so that it only selects those with a value of 5 using the [multiple attribute](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) selector:

```
$(".content-items[name='category[]'][value='5']").prop('checked', false);
```

See example below:

```js
$(".content-items[name='category[]'][value='5']").prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="me-list">
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="1" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter2
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="3" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="container">
    Filter1
   <input class="content-items" type="checkbox" value="5" name="category[]" checked>
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
 </li>
```

*Note*: For demonstration purposes, I added `checked` to each checkbox to show that the checkbox gets unchecked

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.content-items input[name=Category[]')
```

You can iterate over the nodes and whichever node you want to checked false you can do it

```
node.checked = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's change to `$(".content-items input[value=5]").prop('checked', false);`